# Parsley mxml tags are not displayed correctly in Intellij Idea 10+

Tags: validation, intellij-idea, schema, mxml, parsley

I'm trying to use Parsley framework in Intellij Idea 10(11) IDE,
but in doesn't recognize some mxml attributes, giving error "attribute 'type' is not allowed here". But in the Eclipse the mxml parses Ok. Anyone had the problem? Why would it happen?
E.g. "type" is not recognized:

```
<mx:Object xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       xmlns:parsley="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley">
....
<parsley:Object type="{ClientProfile}" id="clientProfile"/>
....
```

When I ctrl-click on **xmlns:parsley** link, I get "**z.xsd**", which is definitely not a valid schema link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z.xsd is a fake and it is correct. There's no real xsd schema for Flex namespaces so IntelliJ IDEA calculates everything on the fly.

I can't reproduce the issue. The code is green for me. How have you configured parsley library for the IDEA module? Can you please share some screenshots?

By the way the best place to ask about Intellij IDEA is our forum which we track more attentively: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity

Comment: Alexander, thank you a lot for answering, I've provided screenshots and more info at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/432880